# Embed YouTube video with reduced volume or mute

Tags: powerpoint, video-capture

**How would I change the embed code for this?**  I am putting a dance video in a PowerPoint, then I am providing an audio narrative describing what is happening in the video. I want the video to autoplay but at a very reduced volume (20%) or to be muted completely. The owner who gave permission could not find his original video, so I have to use his YouTube version.

Here is the YouTube's embed code:

```
iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/yl1l4-5pU7Q" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe
```

I don't know JavaScript or IFrame so I cannot decipher a website that you refer me to... :-(

Comment: [these](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters) are the officially supported parameters; I don't see anything related to audio volume, do you?

Comment: In the audio world, the process you want is called "ducking", where one audio track automatically reduces the volume of another. It's well beyond what PowerPoint is able to do. Here's one program that does that: https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/degaths-ducker.251/

Comment: This sounds a bit simplistic, but YouTube allows the owner to download a video in MP4 format. Could the owner do that and send it to you?